# DataType(DataType.Date) format (MVC)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Can we apply somehow the format for this?

```
[Display(Name = "Date of Birthday")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

I'd like to see only Date and not Time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the *DisplayFormatAttribute*

> Specifies how data fields are displayed and formatted by ASP.NET Dynamic Data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
[Display(Name = "Date of Birthday")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yo.... Hmmm Anyway the time is appears somehow... I  have implemented the datetime field with jQuery Datapicker... I SEE THIS: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Probably I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658501/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-datetime-to-empty-string  I use nullable DateTime so the field is always EMPTY hahahahaha!:)

Comment: Well, that's what you would get for DateTime.MinValue.  I would be surprised if you get that same result for NULL (though I have been surprised before).

Comment: I would also add `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true`, `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`