# How to validate date type field by using jquery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using ASP.NET MVC. I have a problem with calender - date validation.

The codes for this calendar are in the following :

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' }).
    });
</script>

<tr>
 <td style="text-align:left; padding-left:50px;">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.startdate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}",        
             new { @class = "date", style = "width:65px; font-weight: bold;", @readonly = "true" })
 </td>
</tr>
```

I validate the fields of the form by JQuery validation plugin. For this, I included the following two JavaScript libraries;

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

After I added the JavaScript libraries above, the date field can not pass validation and does not work properly.

For example, i have a date like: 19.09.2014.

The day part of the calendar (19) behaves as a month, and the month part of the calendar (09) behaves as day.

How can i solve this problem? I want to get validated date fields and month-day parts of the calender works properly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351109/datatypedatatype-date-format-mvc see this link it may help you to solve this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code do 2 things 1)`Set date format`and 2)`Date format Validation`

```
$(function () {
        $.validator.addMethod('date',
        function (value, element) {
            if (this.optional(element)) {
                return true;
            }
            var valid = true;
            try {
                $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', value);
            }
            catch (err) {
                valid = false;
            }
            return valid;
        });
        $(".datetype").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
    });
```

Add    `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`for validation in your model.