# How to check validation of date input

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How can I check validation when someone try to type in field of date ex. 65.01.2020, so in this way I need something to remind user to type wrong date.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    Year <small>(dd.mm.gggg)</small>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.year, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "10", minlength = "4" })
</div>
```

I use this script for characters:

```
var v = this.value;
if (v.match(/^\d{2}$.) !== null) 
{
    this.value = v + '.';
} 
else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$.) !== null) 
{
    this.value = v + '.'; 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate date type field by using jquery validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934295/how-to-validate-date-type-field-by-using-jquery-validation)

Comment: Good day. A little more detail would be helpful. Can you specify your exact requirement of validation and how the application will respond to incorrect data (disable form post action? Tool Tip? Alert? ). The only posted example of incorrect data is 65.01.2020. The javascript code does not line up with that problem precisely but could be part of the larger validation script that could be included. Also, you may want to look at the asp validation classes and how those may be helpful.

Comment: @Bill I have two input fields YearFrom and YearTo and I need date validation with ex. alert, that can be done with mask and blur from field to filed, but that solution is unrecognizable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regular expression to validate:

```
function ValidateDate(testdate) 
{
  var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/;
    if (!(date_regex.test(testdate))) {
        return false;
    }  
}
```

This is working for me for `MM/dd/yyyy`.

For `DD/MM/YYYY` use

```
  var date_regex = /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d/;
```

Comment: Should I put this with my existing script or.. And in my way it is `DD.MM.YYY`

Comment: check my edited answer , its for `DD/MM/YYYY`

Comment: in this condition `if (!(date_regex.test(testDate))) {
    return false;
}` test and testDate what should I put here, my class or something else?

Comment: put your `input` value (means your `input date` )

Comment: this is how it looks like in my inspect element `<input class="form-control" id="year" name="year" type="text" value="">`, so i need to put `date_regex.value(year)` is that correct?

Comment: what you get in  `var v = this.value;` ? if you get value of your `date` input then you have to take this value

Answer (score 0):

**#** if you are considering one of js supportd formats:
ex: `"yyyy-MM-DD", "MM-DD-yyyy", "MMM DD yyyy" or "DD MMM yyyy"`
you can use this simple check:

```
const validatedDate = new Date(YOUR DATE HERE);
if (isNaN(validateDate.getTime()) { 
  // the date is invalid
} else {
  // the date is valid
}
```

**#** if you are considering different formats:

1. I'd recommend using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) or any of the alternative libraries

ex: `moment("2010 11 31", "YYYY MM DD").isValid();`

2. if you don't want to use any library and you want to do it yourself, you'll need more than just a regex test, don't forget about checking if the year is a leap year, so if you have 29 February you can check if it's a valid date or not, also for other months you need to check if each of them has 30 or 31 days, you'll need to check all these rules manually
   in this case, most probably you'll need to split your values:

ex: for `const d = "25-10-2009"` you can do `const [day, month, year] = d.split('-')`
then you'll need to check the predefined rules based on these values